# Sync notification across multiple android devices

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I have a Galaxy Note 8.0 and a Galaxy s3. Both running on 4.1.2. All of my accounts are synced on both devices.  That is why I get the same notif on both device.

I have searched and found that Google mentioned this on their I/O,  I think last June.. But i am not aware if this is being implemented.

Is there a way to sync notifications across android devices?
For example,  when I swipe a notif on my S3,  the notif that is on the Note too will be deleted. 
If I close a Facebook chat head or replied to that person,  the notif of it on my Note would also be closed.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: It's called user notifications. See the answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073229/how-to-implement-mqtt-in-this-particular-usecase-of-android/).

Comment: Sir Eran im sorry but i do n8y understand any words about it.. i dont know what should i do with those codes.. im sorry..

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions, which is why Eran answered the way he did.  You should ask in SuperUser or even better android.stackexchange.com about user level stuff.